# Assign two functions to the same button?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to attach a click event to a button to pop more div. I also want the same button to
do another functon after more divs are poped and the button is clicked. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

my code:

Jquery

```
$('#add').click(function(){
        $('.detail').fadeIn(300);
        $(this).attr('id', 'add_go');

     })


$('#add_go').click(function(){
     //same button click the second time
     alert('second function!');
})
```

html

```
<div>
   <a href='#' id='add'>add</div>

<div class='detail' style='display:none;'>more dive</div>
<div class='detail' style='display:none;'>more dive</div>
<div class='detail' style='display:none;'>more dive</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This will work perfectly as-is, except that you haven't used the same ID in the jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd keep it the one function in the situation you've described:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
      //Check if divs are visible
      if($('.detail').is(':visible'){
         alert('second function');   
      }else{            
         $('.detail').fadeIn(300);
      }
})
```